# GPU serializations decomposition

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

According to this, http://www.nvidia.co.uk/content/PDF/isc-2011/Ziegler.pdf, I understand that replays in the GPU literature mean serializations. But what are the factors that contribute to the number of serializations?

To do this, I did some experiments. Profiled a some kernels and find the number of replays (= issued instructions - executed instructions). Sometimes, the number of bank conflicts to be equal to the number of replays. Some other times, the number of bank conflicts is smaller. This implies the number of bank conflicts is always a factor. What about the other?

According to the slides above (from slides 35), there are some others:

. The instruction cache misses

. Constant memory bank conflicts

To my understanding, there can be two others:

. The number of branches divergences. Since both paths are executed, there are replays. But i'm not sure if the number of issued instructions are affected by divergences or not?

. The number of cache misses. I have heard that long latency memory requests will be replayed sometimes. But in my experiments, L1 cache misses are often higher than replays.

Can anyone confirm these factors are those contribute to serializations? What is incorrect and do I miss something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know branch divergence contributes to instruction replay.

I am not sure about the number of cache misses. That should be handled transparently by the memory controller not affecting the instruction. Worse thing I can think is that the pipeline gets stopped until the memory has been properly fetched.

Comment: Yeah I think divergences would be part of instructions replays too. But when as I've seen, the sum of divergences and bank conflicts is bigger than the replays!